# Is there a way to create public/private fields for a mongodb schema in golang?

Tags: mongodb, go

I'm creating a backend for a moderately large-scale application, and I came across a difficulty with restraining what fields users can access. For instance, a user should not be able to modify their follower count with a `PUT` request to an update endpoint, yet the only way to really remove the followerCount field from the golang struct representing the user schema is by creating an entirely new schema for updates in particular. I've been doing this, and my backend code base is way more complex than it needs to be, to the point where it's nearly unmanageable.

Here's an example of the schemas I have:

```golang
type User struct {
    ID primitive.ObjectID `bson:"_id" json:"_id"`

    // CHANGEABLE
    Username string `bson:"username" json:"username"`
    Email    string `bson:"email" json:"email"`
    Password string `bson:"password" json:"password"`
    Archived bool   `bson:"archived" json:"archived"`

    // UNCHANGEABLE
    Sessions  []primitive.ObjectID `bson:"sessions" json:"sessions"`
    IsCreator bool                 `bson:"isCreator" json:"isCreator"`
        FollowerCount int              `bson:"followerCount" json:"followerCount"`
}
```

and for updates specifically

```
type UserUpdate struct {
    Username string `bson:"username,omitempty" json:"username,omitempty"`
    Email    string `bson:"email,omitempty" json:"email,omitempty"`
    Password string `bson:"password,omitempty" json:"password,omitempty"`
    Archived bool   `bson:"archived,omitempty" json:"archived,omitempty"`
}
```

Is there a way to make public/private fields within a mongo schema so I can simplify this process? And if not, can you advise me on a better solution? Nothing is coming to mind for me.

I've continued creating new "sub-schemas" built off the same schema for specific purposes (i.e. Creation, Updating, Getting, etc.). Changing one field name takes nearly 30 minutes to change across schemas, which is not ideal.

Comment: I use maps in situations like this

Comment: Would you mind elaborating @ABDULLOKHMUKHAMMADJONOV ?

Comment: This isn't a job for field access restrictions in code, this is a job for input validation. The same code that makes sure the email is valid should make sure they're not modifying a field they're not allowed to modify.